# Different inputs into dictionary all come out the same

Tags: c#, dictionary, kinect

So I am putting some data into a dictionary. A String (name) and a Bone (used to hold position and stuff). I am reading from the kinect what the position of the bone is, then I am putting it into the dictionary then later on I am saving them to a .txt file. Now I am pretty confused because all of them are the same. For a while I have a few labels showing the different positions of a few bones, and they were all changing. So that means it has to do with my putting into the dictionary?

Here is my input method:

```
        JointCollection joints = skele.Joints;
        List<Bone> temp = current_bones;
        Frame temp_f = new Frame(temp);
        Joint h_j = joints[JointType.Head];
        foreach (Joint j in joints)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (j.JointType)
                {
                    #region cases
                    case (JointType.Head):
                        temp_f.frame_bones["Head"].setPosition(j.Position.X, j.Position.Y, j.Position.Z);
                        break;
...Other stuff that basically repeats but with different jointtypes
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { /*MessageBox.Show("Error getting joints: " + ex.Message);*/ }
        }
        if (recording)
        {
            if (newR)
            {
                bvhBuilder.resetAnimation();    //Resets a list of frames
                newR = false;
            }
            bvhBuilder.add_frame(temp_f);//adds a frame to the list
        }
```

Main stuff in Bone class:

```
public Bone(String b_name)
    {
        name = b_name;
    }

    public void setPosition(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        x = _x; y = _y; z = _z; 
    }
```

relevent stuff in my BVHBuilder class:

```
List<Bone> current_bones = new List<Bone>();
    Frame current_frame;
    List<Frame> animation_frames = new List<Frame>();
    public BVHBuilder(List<Bone> bones)
    {
        current_bones = bones;
    }
public String build()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine(build_bones());
        builder.AppendLine(build_anim());
        return builder.ToString();
    }

 public String build_anim()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("MOTION");
        sb.AppendLine("Frames: " + getFrameCount());
        sb.AppendLine("Frame Time: " + (float)((float)1/(float)30));
        foreach (Frame frame in animation_frames)
        {
            String line = "";
            int b_i = 0;
            float root_x = frame.root.x;
            float root_y = frame.root.y;
            float root_z = frame.root.z;
            Console.WriteLine("Root: (" + root_x + "," + root_y + "," + root_z + ")"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < frame.frame_bones.Count; i++)
            {
                Bone bone = frame.frame_bones.Values.ElementAt(i);
                line += (bone.x - root_x) + " ";
                line += (bone.y - root_y) + " ";
                if (b_i >= frame.frame_bones.Count) { line += (root_z - bone.z); }   //Don't want a space at the end
                else { line += (root_z - bone.z) + " "; }

                b_i++;
            }
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Frame class:

```
class Frame
{
    public Dictionary<String, Bone> frame_bones = new Dictionary<String, Bone>();
    public Bone root = null;
    int root_pos = 0;

    public Frame(List<Bone> bones)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Bone b in bones)
        {
            frame_bones.Add(b.name,b);
            if (b.root) { root_pos = i; root = b; }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where it saves:

```
private void saveAnim()
    {
        int times = 0;
        String path = "";
        Boolean exists = true;
        while (exists)
        {
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + "nectrecord" + times + ".txt";
            exists = File.Exists(path);
            times++;
        }
        currP = path;
        Console.WriteLine(currP);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(currP);
        String write = bvhBuilder.build();
        int max_i = write.Length;
        progressBar1.Maximum = max_i;
        int c_i = 0;
        foreach (char c in write)
        {
            sw.Write(c);
            c_i++;
            progressBar1.Value = c_i;
        }
        sw.Flush();//make sure everything wrote
        sw.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved to :" + currP);
    }
```

I know that is a lot of code, but I have been trying to debug this for probably 4 hours now. Hopefully a fresh pair of eyes will help me find the problem.

Btw this is what the output file looks like:

```
HIERARCHY
ROOT Hip_C
{
OFFSET 0 0 0
CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
JOINT Spine
{
    OFFSET 0 0 0
    CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
    JOINT Shoulder_C
    {
        OFFSET 0 0 0
        CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
        JOINT Head
        {
            OFFSET 0 0 0
            CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
        }
        JOINT Shoulder_R
        {
            OFFSET 0 0 0
            CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
            JOINT Elbow_R
            {
                OFFSET 0 0 0
                CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
                JOINT Wrist_R
                {
                    OFFSET 0 0 0
                    CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
                    JOINT Hand_R
                    {
                        OFFSET 0 0 0
                        CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        JOINT Shoulder_L
        {
            OFFSET 0 0 0
            CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
            JOINT Elbow_L
            {
                OFFSET 0 0 0
                CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
                JOINT Wrist_L
                {
                    OFFSET 0 0 0
                    CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
                    JOINT Hand_L
                    {
                        OFFSET 0 0 0
                        CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
JOINT Hip_R
{
    OFFSET 0 0 0
    CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
    JOINT Knee_R
    {
        OFFSET 0 0 0
        CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
        JOINT Ankle_R
        {
            OFFSET 0 0 0
            CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
            JOINT Foot_R
            {
                OFFSET 0 0 0
                CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
            }
        }
    }
}
JOINT Hip_L
{
    OFFSET 0 0 0
    CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
    JOINT Knee_L
    {
        OFFSET 0 0 0
        CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
        JOINT Ankle_L
        {
            OFFSET 0 0 0
            CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
            JOINT Foot_L
            {
                OFFSET 0 0 0
                CHANNELS 3 Xposition Yposition Zposition
            }
        }
    }
}
}



MOTION
Frames: 210
 Frame Time: 0.03333334
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.05713073 -0.009174455 -0.2937571 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.902887 0.2087359 -0.2028138 -0.9028869 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

...and that continues for a while

Comment: This should be the longest question I have seen on SO!

Comment: I know.. I have no other way to ask it xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it had to do with some problem with the frame class maybe? Cause I mad a List and put the data directly into it and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You only make `temp_f` one time before the `foreach` and yet you always add that same list to the dictionary?

Furthermore you use `BVHBuilder.add_frame` when no `add_frame` seems declared on that... I suppose you means `Frame` or omitted the code.

Comment: Ya. I am not sure how...
btw this is .addframe: public void add_frame(Frame frame) { animation_frames.Add(frame); }